# Duplicate index with and without include column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing

While investigating my database with [sp_BlitzIndex](http://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/) script of [Brent Ozar](http://www.brentozar.com/). I find some duplicate index issues Multiple Index Personalities: Duplicate keys.

Duplicate index issue is for following indexes.

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_Business] ON [dbo].[tblMobile] ( [BusinessID] );
CREATE INDEX [IX_Comb_Marketing] ON [dbo].[tblMobile] ( [BusinessID] ) INCLUDE ( [MobileNo]);
```

The difference between this two index is

```
INCLUDE ( [MobileNo]);
```

Now, I am confuse about how to tackle with duplicate index issue. I can't delete first index without include column, Can I delete index with include column? Do I need to include column `MobileNo` in first index and can delete second?

What is the effect if I delete second one and do not include column in first index?

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you delete the first index? Queries using that will still be able to use the second index.

Comment: What if first index is cluster index with primary key?

Comment: Well it isn't according to the `CREATE INDEX` statements in your question.

Comment: If you drop the second index (with the included column), then if you have a query that's using `BusinessID` to find a row and then returns that ID plus the `MobileNo`, right now, this query can be satisfied from the index. If you drop that index, then in order to get the `MobileNo` column, SQL Server will have to do an expensive **key lookup** into the base table and get that column. Therefore, execution of that particular query will take a lot longer

Comment: @MartinSmith Consider this two index `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StateMaster] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_StateMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [StateId] );` and second(duplicate) index is
`CREATE INDEX [IX_Combo_State_Data_Entry] ON [dbo].[StateMaster] ( [StateId] ) INCLUDE ( [Name]);` now this index is clustered. which one I have to delete?

Comment: Well the clustered index implicitly includes all columns in the table so the second one. Though there might be a case for keeping both if the leaf level of the NCI is much narrower depending on the queries that use it.

Comment: Check the index usage statistics to see if either of them are actually being used (be aware that as it's a dmv it gets cleared after a restart so you want to monitor it for a while), you might find you can get rid of both.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest evaluating de seeks for both index. Take in concern the time from the last restart of the server (Statistics will reset).

To evaluate seeks.

```
select  'TableName' = object_name(I.object_id)
, 'IndexName' = [I].[name] 
, U.user_seeks
 , U.user_scans
 , U.user_updates
 , U.last_user_seek
 , U.last_user_scan

         FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats U
              INNER JOIN SYS.INDEXES AS I ON I.[OBJECT_ID] = U.[OBJECT_ID]
                                             AND I.INDEX_ID = U.INDEX_ID
```